# Spring Integration: Parallel processing

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I have a spring message listener which received prices for stocks ( S1, S2, S3 ...).  The prices for same stock need to be processed sequentially where as prices for different stocks should be processed parallel.

e.g. if sequence of prices are S1-1, S1-2, S2-1, S1-3, S3-1, S2-2, S1-3, S3-2 ..
then there should be three parallel stream of processing

S1-1, S1-2, S1-3

S2-1, S2-1

S3-1, S3-2

Currently I am processing everything in parallel, The message listener sends messages to priceInChannel as soos as it arrives.

```
<int:channel id="priceInChannel">
    <int:dispatcher task-executor="threadPoolExecutor"/>
</int:channel>
```

What changes would be required for me to achieve required behaviour?

Thanks
Murali

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should do this:

1. aggregate prices for each stock to have bags S1, S2, S3 ...
2. resequence those bags. Here will be need to do some tricks around `sequenceDatails`
3. split each stock to prices to an `executor-channel`.

Of course, this solution depends of how how much incoming data you have and how long they all come to.

**UPDATE**

> I believe I can't aggregate as it is a series of continuous prices

OK. Makes sense.

Well, how about to have a `router` and **queue** channels for each series.

Stocks will be processed in parallel, but each price in stock will be sequential, because the queue channel will bock underlying handler until the end of message. Of course, if your `poller` for the queue channel is:

```
<poller max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-delay="100"/>
```

Comment: I believe I can't aggregate as it it a series of continuous prices